# Ggpairs barDiag with normal curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpairs

I am using the ggpairs from ggplot2.

I need to get an histogram in the diagonal for the ggpairs, but want to superimpose the normal density curve using the mean and sd of the data.

I read the help (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GGally/versions/1.4.0/topics/ggpairs) but can't find an option to do it. I guess I must built my own function (myfunct) and then

`ggpairs(sample.dat, diag=list(continuous = myfunct))`

Has anyone have tried this?

---

I have tried the following:

```
head(data) 
      x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6     F1    F2 
1 -0.749 -1.57 0.408 0.961 0.777 0.171 -0.143 0.345 

myhist = function(data){ 
          ggplot(data, aes(x)) + 
             geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),colour = "black") + 
             stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))) 
           } 

ggpairs(sample.data, diag=list(continuous = myhist))
```

The result is:

> Error in (function (data) : unused argument (mapping = list(~x1))

Comment: as you mention, just write your own function. relevant plotting code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967664/ggplot2-histogram-with-normal-curve

Comment: ... yes, but since I have a data frame, I am not sure how to do it.
I have tried:

Comment: I have tried the following:


```head(data)

      x1     x2      x3     x4     x5     x6     F1     F2
1 -0.749 -1.57   0.408   0.961  0.777  0.171 -0.143  0.345
```

```myhist = function(data){
ggplot(data, aes(x))  + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),colour = "black")  +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
}```

```
ggpairs(sample.data, diag=list(continuous = myhist))
```
The result is:

Error in (function (data)  : unused argument (mapping = list(~x1))

Comment: I just don't know how to pass the data into the mean=mean() argument of the stat_function

Comment: JPMD; Ive added a quick example.

Comment: ... and https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/#custom_functions provides some better docs and examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967664/ggplot2-histogram-with-normal-curve) provides an example of the code to add a normal curve to a histogram in `ggplot2`. You can use this to write your own function to pass to the `diag` argument of `ggpairs`. To calculate the `mean` and `sd` of the data, you can grab the relevant data using, for example, `eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)`. Example below (perhaps a little more complicated than needed but it allows you to pass parameters to change colours etc using the `wrap` functionality.

```
library(GGally)    

diag_fun <- function(data, mapping, hist=list(), ...){

    X = eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)
    mn = mean(X)
    s = sd(X)

    ggplot(data, mapping) + 
      do.call(function(...) geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..), ...), hist) +
      stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mn, sd = s), ...)
  }

ggpairs(iris[1:100, 1:4], 
        diag=list(continuous=wrap(diag_fun, hist=list(fill="red", colour="blue"), 
                                  colour="green", lwd=2)))
```

Comment: Thank you user20650. The  `X=eval_data_col` part solved my problem!...

Comment: you're welcome. To get an idea of how to do things it is worth looking at the underlying R code, for example, `GGally::ggally_density`