# R: Plotting histogram with bell curve

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a histogram and fit a bell curve. I got different measurements in diameter and group by gender. I'm not sure how to fit a bell curve.
My code for the histogram is the following.

```
body %>% histogram(~ diameter|gender, col="dodgerblue3",
                   layout=c(1,2), data=., xlab="Diameter")
```

Here is a sample of my data. The file I've saved as is body.csv.

| Diameter | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 31.5 | Male |
| 34 | Male |
| 33.2 | Male |
| 32.3 | Male |
| 31 | Male |
| 34 | Male |
| 31.5 | Female |
| 34 | Female |
| 33.2 | Female |
| 32.3 | Female |
| 31 | Female |
| 34 | Female |

Comment: Please use ```dput()``` and produce a sample of your data frame.

Comment: It does not show how to do it by group

Comment: Do you want to add a density plot of your data or a fitted normal distribution?

Comment: I want the histogram with the normal curve.

Comment: Take look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095850/12505251).

Comment: @MartinGal Thanks this is what I was looking for.