# Add dnorm-curve to ggplot geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve

For my thesis I need to plot a histogram of several variables and I want to add a dnorm curve to it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. oes_scale is a standardized variable.

```
ggplot(data, aes(oes_scale)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.35, fill = "darkgrey", color = "black") +
  xlim(-2.5, 3) +
  ylim(0, 70) +
  labs(x="Soziale Ausgrenzung", y="Häufigkeit") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(data$oes_scale), sd = sd(data$oes_scale)), color = "black", size = 1) +
  theme_apa(legend.font.size = 11)
```

I tried this but the curve seems to be very wide. I have tried several things, which all haven't worked. I tried to get the relative frequencies with

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = oes_scale, y = ..density.. * 0.35)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.35, fill = "darkgrey", color = "black") +
  xlim(-2, 3) +
  ylim(0, 0.25) +
  stat_function(fun = ~dnorm(.x, mean = mean(data$oes_scale), sd = sd(data$oes_scale))) +
  labs(x = "Soziale Ausgrenzung", y = "Relative Häufigkeit") +
  theme_apa(legend.font.size = 11)
```

which worked without the stat_function but when I try to add it to the plot, I get this message:

Error in `stat_function()`:
! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `density * 0.35`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Backtrace:

1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
3. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
4. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
5. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
6. l$map_statistic(d, plot)
7. ggplot2 (local) map_statistic(..., self = self)
8. base::lapply(new, eval_tidy, mask, env)
9. rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
   Warning message:
   Removed 6 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_bin()`).

Does anyone have any tips on what I could try?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967664/ggplot2-histogram-with-normal-curve ? Can you explain why your situation is different from this question?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.