# Fitting a Gumbel distribution with fitdistrplus

Tags: r, model-fitting, fitdistrplus

I'm trying to reproduce the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6848958/4124334), however I have problems in doing so. I'm using the gumbel distribution from package `VGAM` and `fitdistrplus`.
The problem emerges when doing:

```
fit   = fitdist(data1, 'gumbel', start = list(location = 0, scale = 1))
Error in mledist(data, distname, start, fix.arg, ...) : 
  'start' must specify names which are arguments to 'distr'.
```

As if `location` and `scale` were not arguments of *gumbel.

`dgumbel`, `pgumbel`, `rgumbel` and `qgumbel` are correctly provided by `VGAM`.
However the package also provides a function called `gumbel`, with different syntax. May this be causing problems?

EDIT: yes indeed it is causing problems: using package `FAdist` instead works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, from the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf) linked in comments:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
data(groundbeef)
serving <- groundbeef$serving
dgumbel <- function(x, a, b) 1/b*exp((a-x)/b)*exp(-exp((a-x)/b))
pgumbel <- function(q, a, b) exp(-exp((a-q)/b))
qgumbel <- function(p, a, b) a-b*log(-log(p))
fitgumbel <- fitdist(serving, "gumbel", 
    start=list(a=10, b=10))
```

Or with the functions from `VGAM`:

```
rm(dgumbel) ## get rid of previous definition
## hack behaviour of VGAM::pgumbel() a little bit
pgumbel <- function(x,...) {
  if (length(x)==0) numeric(0) else VGAM::pgumbel(x,...)
}
library(VGAM)
fitgumbel <- fitdist(serving, "gumbel", 
       start=list(location=10, scale=10))
```

Comment: Any ideas on the definiton of rgumbel? I got "The rgumbel  function must be defined" when using bootdist

Comment: have you tried `library("sos"); findFn("rgumbel")`? `VGAM`, `evd` packages, probably others ... might need to wrap/redefine to change the parameterization ...

Comment: EDIT: It seems that's random gumbel... Now, any clues what that function looks like?

Comment: seems like you should formulate this as a new question ... ?

Answer (score -2):

start=list(mu=R,s=R)
R=your params

Comment: Please, add some explanation for your formula (or code in general).

Answer (score -2):

This is because the fitdistr package do not support gumbel distribution.

Comment: Do you have any source, explanation or reference?

Comment: if you use 'gumbel' it says : unsupported distribution. Then in the package documentation: 'Distributions "beta", "cauchy", "chi-squared", "exponential", "f", "gamma", "geometric", "log-normal", "lognormal", "logistic", "negative binomial", "normal", "Poisson", "t" and "weibull" are recognised, case being ignored. Libraries ismev and EnvStats can estimate gumbel parameters

Comment: actually the "gumbel" distribution is used also in the package docs: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf, page 29, with a custom-defined gumbel. Why does the gumbel from `VGAM` not work? By the way in the above documentation the string you mentioned is not present. Where did you get it? Please provide links.

Comment: But you have to define the gumbel distribution by your own to get the fit.