# For an extreme distribution in R eg plot(GumbelDistribution)

Tags: r

Do you take the leftmost tail data at a certain point rather than the whole distribution data to get the correct distribution.

```
Gumbel_density <- exp(-ts_rSPY)
plot(ts_rSPY,Gumbel_density, col='green')
```

the plot does not show a gumbel density
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847658/11570343).

Comment: `stat_function` does not have all the distribution functions so you would have to do them [yourself](https://dk81.github.io/dkmathstats_site/rvisual-cont-prob-dists.html).

Comment: None of those plots work as a gumbel distribution all I could get to work was a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to plot a Gumble distribution:

```
set.seed(4545)
size = 1e6 # desired size for result array
mu = 1 # location parameter
beta = 2.5 # scale parameter
result = mu - beta*log(-log(runif(size)))
plot(density(result), main = '', type = 'l',
    xlab = 'X', ylab = '', col = 'green')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was after a plot using ggplot2 thanks.  For extreme value distributions, they are available built-in for most Evt packages with the default plot library, whereas few if any use ggplot2.

Comment: Checking the parameters yours will work so it is a matter of converting to GGplot2. However you would have to run fitdist on real data, will just stick with default plots in extreme value packages, too much trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your help I have done it in ggplot2 eventually.